# Coherence length of velocity field in cosmology

Tags: cosmology

While reading a paper I came across a term 'coherence length of velocity field in cosmology' .....I have searched for this ,but didn't get any result...can anyone please help me getting this understood....(the paper is by Nicholas Kaiser titled "why there is no Newtonian backreaction"

Comment: Can anyone please help me out here...it is coherence length of peculiar velocity field

Comment: I made an effort looking at https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/469/1/744/3737674 . I got stumped on the meaning of the variable (in script format) Q.  Whatever the discussion in this article is, this variable seems to be the critical element. There also seems to be a lot of references to Buchert. I recommend you try to locate these references  and search for the (script) Q. I also found the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_length , but it did not use the notation Q.